# Softwares para recuperação de arquivos na MFT (Master File Table)

Tags: análise-de-dados

Olá, eu trabalho muito com sistemas de arquivos NTFS. Eu já perdi muitos arquivos, por falhas lógicas e físicas nas minhas mídias. Sempre consegui recuperar alguns arquivos com muito esforço e pesquisas técnicas sobre o assunto. Eu fiz um programa em Pascal, porque eu conseguia sempre recuperar arquivos RAW (fotos, músicas, etc) de uma unidade danificada, com algumas ferramentas no mercado que prometiam isso. Mas como a estrutura do disco está corrompida, não há como saber do que se trata cada arquivo, a menos que eu abra cada um deles. Então, diante de uma situação em que eu tinha acesso aos meus arquivos no disco (pastas e arquivos), mas quase tudo estava corrompido, eu criei um programa capaz de comparar esses arquivos corrompidos, com nome e data de criação, com as pilhas de arquivos RAW recuperados. Assim, quando um arquivo corrompido tiver a mesma extensão e tamanho em bytes de outro arquivo RAW em bom estado, presume-se que o arquivo RAW é o arquivo correto. Então, o arquivo de origem danificado é substituído, opcionalmente em outra unidade, o que é recomendado.

http://www.github.com/ngbios/mftrebuilder/

Mas, como nada é perfeito, percebi que muitos arquivos não são encontrados de forma crua pelas ferramentas de recuperação. Sempre quando tentamos copia-los com programas de recuperação, como Getdataback e afins, o arquivo sempre está corrompido, porque os endereços dos clusters não correspondem mais ao conteúdo do arquivo. Mas se procurarmos num editor hexadecimal, acaba-se encontrando o começo do arquivo logo a frente. Eu pensei que talvez eu conseguisse recuperar arquivos desta maneira, se descobrisse algum desalinhamento dos endereços originais da MFT. Por exemplo, eu tenho um arquivo que começa em no endereço 200, mas logicamente, começa apenas no endereço 207. Ou posso ter um arquivo que começa no endereço 214, mas está localizado no endereço 221.

Enfim, eu perdi meus dados quando corrompi a MBR do disco. Então, eu criei uma imagem clonada do HD, e formatei ele para continuar usando. Mas algo deu errado no backup da imagem, que fez ela ficar incompleta. Daí no final do disco, provavelmente tinha alguma cópia da MFT mais recente. A MFT que eu tenho provavelmente tem endereços antigos de arquivos que talvez foram realocados ou foram alterados de lugar com o desfragmentador de disco. Prefiro acreditar nisso, pois eu recuperei muitos arquivos inteiros,e provavelmente isso foi uma consequência do desfragmentador de disco do Windows.

Eu queria trocar alguma experiência com pessoas que podem ter alguma solução para o meu problema. Talvez eu consiga recuperar meus dados com alguma técnica, ou algum software que eu não conheço. Eu nunca vi no mercado alguma ferramenta pequena como eu fiz. Imagino que isso seria muito útil, pois muitas pessoas perdem arquivos, e quando recuperam, estão todos embaralhados com números ao invés do nome original do arquivo. E se as pessoas conseguirem recuperar as entradas da MFT, podem ter os dados de volta, pelo menos alguns.